# Move a sequential range of numbered files to new directories

Tags: command-line

In my parent directory I have 78,160 files.
File names are: sb_604_dpm_0089000.dpx, sb_604_0089001.dpx etc.

I want to move the files to 4 sub directories subdir1, subdir2, subdir3, subdir4.
There must be exactly 20,000 files in each directory in sequential order.

Is it to possible to move a certain range of files from the parent directory to the sub-directories i.e.,
sb_604_dpm_0089000.dpx to sb_604_dpm_0108,999.dpx files to subdir1
sb_604_dpm_0109000.dpx to sb_604_dpm_0128,999.dpx files to subdir2
etc.

The final folder will only contain the remaining files after the first 60,000.

All of these should be done using a batch file, ideally being able to specify/check the range before the move proceeds. Is this possible?

In DOS I would probably be able to work this out for myself writing a batch file, but with Linux I'm a little lost...
I'm not a programmer, I'm just a linux user looking for faster/better ways to do this rather than the GUI, so any help appreciated. Please keep it as simple as possible!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I will write you a quick script... one sec

Answer (score 5):

If it's a one-time task, you could use shell expansion like so:

```
mkdir subdir1 subdir2 subdir3 subdir4
mv sb_604_dpm_{0089000..0108999}.dpx subdir1
mv sb_604_dpm_{0109000..0128999}.dpx subdir2
mv sb_604_dpm_{0129000..0148999}.dpx subdir3
mv sb_604_dpm_*.dpx                  subdir4
```

`{1..5}` expands to `1 2 3 4 5`, so the above commands expand to the first/second/third 20,000 files, and the last line handles the rest.

Comment: That was quick - thank-you PerlDuck!

Comment: +1 because OP will be more likely to understand it than something more fancy.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this little script should do it for you:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

files=(*.dpx)
folder=1
count=0

if [ ! -d "folder$folder" ]; then
   mkdir "folder$folder"
fi

for i in "${files[@]}"
do
   mv "$i" "folder$folder"
   let count=$count+1
   if [ "$count" == "20000" ]; then
      let count=0
      let folder=$folder+1
      if [ ! -d "folder$folder" ]; then
        mkdir "folder$folder"
      fi
   fi
done
```

Put script into a file inside of the folder with the files you want to move (eg folder in your home folder named "my-files") and name the file "move". Then from the command line:

```
$ cd ~/my-files
$ chmod 755 move
$ ./move
```

Comment: +1 Because this is way more flexible than [my _hardcoded_ suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/a/1035018/504066). It _might_ be a bit slow because `mv` is called 78,160 times (instead of 4 times). But an old rule says: don't optimize before profiling.

Comment: Out of curiosity I just measured: 
 **1)** create 20k files: `touch sb_604_dpm_{0089000..0108999}.dpx`
 **2)** move one by one: `time for i in sb_604_dpm_{0089000..0108999}.dpx; do mv $i subdir1/; done` gives 25 seconds.
 **3)** move all at once: `time mv sb_604_dpm_{0089000..0108999}.dpx subdir1/` gives 0.4 seconds.
But still: If it's a one-time task I wouldn't care. I just spent more time diagnosing than it actually took.

Comment: This is def not the fastest solution, but it works ;)

Comment: Thank-you Joshua. Sorry to ask a basic question, but how do I implement that script...? In DOS I just used to save it as a batch file and double click - what is the Linux equivalent?